# Can I change the value of a property inside a redux state using a value passed in during the action call by the user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to change the redux state, which is an object, but the property of the object that needs to be changed depends upon what the user wants to change. The state has properties in it that represent different rows in a table, and since there are a lot, I cant have a specific case for each one. So for example, instead of saying I want to change row1, I want to change action.row.

Here's some code of how it would be normally:

```
case 'CHANGE_STATE': {
      return {
        ...state, row1: action.payload
      }
    }
```

And here's an example of how I want it to work

```
case 'CHANGE_STATE': {
      return {
        ...state, action.row: action.payload
      }
    }
```

Where action.row is provided when calling the redux action.

Comment: This has already answered, but please generally note that this is a very old style of Redux and we recommend using the official Redux Tookit instead since 2019. Please give [Why Redux Toolkit is how to write Redux Today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) a read. You will write only 1/4 of the code with that.

Comment: Yes, the new toolkit is great, I just need to use the old version for work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables as object keys using a bracket notation:

```js
{
  ...state, [action.row]: action.payload
}
```

Comment: Wow, facepalm. So simple! Thanks so much!